# Android background download on WiFi only

Tags: android, service, android-download-manager

My app requires to download files in the evening if there is Wi-Fi. Is `Service` the best way to implement it?

If user closes my app, does that mean I cannot download in any way? That means my user has to keep my app in the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use `DownloadManager` and restrict the allowed network types to Wi-Fi only.

For example:

```
DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://something.xyz/somefile.asd");

DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
// allowing Wi-Fi only
request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);

long id = manager.enqueue(request);
```

To get notified when your download completes, you could define a receiver for the `ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` broadcast:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver downloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // the ID of the finished download
        long downloadedId = intent.getLongExtra(
            DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);

        // do whatever you'd like here
    }
};
```

And register/unregister it:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(downloadReceiver,
        new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(downloadReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Don't forget to add the appropriate permissions to your *Manifest*:

```
<!-- required -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- optional -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run sticky service , you can download your files in worker threads not main threads even your app is closed.Therefore after finishing you can use broadcast receiver to notify the user or start an activity.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that

Answer (score 0):

You can use services even when your app is closed. I recommend using [IntentService](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiisZy1mITPAhVG3SwKHfReBeMQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fapp%2FIntentService.html&usg=AFQjCNFVhrLvwgyBHq8BhrQ6iNxhEwcrZA). It is easy to use and it runs in a thread other than your UI thread. You can also make it STICKY so that your service will be restarted even if Android kills it.